# error making connection with database in xcode? cannot connect with the database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

i am using sqlite manager thourgh the add-on on firefox.

i have made an empty database and that database is stored where my crud app is stored.

Note! : this is my first crud Application on IOS i am facing problem connecting with database and for crud it is obvious to first connect to database.

The Steps I have Followed Are:

1. open sqlite manager form firefox made a db named productsDB.sqlite and save this to the same folder where i create my app.
2. i have include the libsqlite3.0.dylib also.
3. Then i have add the database into the Application by right click and add file....
4. Then i have write the code for connectivity by passing it into string.

[Getting error while inserting data to my table in database using 'storyboard' i.e "no visible interface..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770693/getting-error-while-inserting-data-to-my-table-in-database-using-storyboard-i/18770788?noredirect=1#comment27678885_18770788)

this links leads to the connectivity code.

I am using storyboard.

Comment: Dear All I have Teamview also anyone can see the code and edit it and can check what procedures i have followed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For learners like me i would suggest them to make a simple core data app once you made it then you will know how to import add an isolated db.
By the way core data itself make an sqlite db for you.
so first go through the core data as it is the first step to play with db programming in IOS.

Comment: use base as a tool to view and edit the database `BASE` i found better then sqlite firefox extension.